# How to adapt this QuickSort (coded in C language) algortim to an array of strings?

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting, quicksort

I need to sort the content (alphabetically using `strcmp()` of an array of strings, but I am not allowed to use the function `qsort()`. With this code I managed to sort numerical values, but I am having a hard time adapting it in order to sort strings.

```
/* A utility function to swap two elements */
void swap(int* a, int* b) 
{ 
    int t = *a; 
    *a = *b; 
    *b = t; 
} 

void swap_string(char c[63], char d[63]){
    char temp[63];
    strcpy(temp, c);
    strcpy(c, d);
    strcpy(d, temp);
}

/* This function takes last element as pivot, places 
   the pivot element at its correct position in sorted 
    array, and places all smaller (smaller than pivot) 
   to left of pivot and all greater elements to right 
   of pivot */
int partition (int arr[], int low, int high) 
{ 
    int pivot = arr[high];    /* pivot */
    int i = (low - 1);  /* Index of smaller element */

    for (j = low; j <= high- 1; j++) 
    { 
        /* If current element is smaller than the pivot */
        if (arr[j] < pivot) 
        { 
            i++;    /* increment index of smaller element */
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]); 
        } 
    } 
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]); 
    return (i + 1); 
} 

/* The main function that implements QuickSort 
 arr[] --> Array to be sorted, 
  low  --> Starting index, 
  high  --> Ending index */
void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high) 
{ 
    if (low < high) 
    { 
        /* pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now 
           at right place */
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high); 

        /* Separately sort elements before */
        /* partition and after partition */
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1); 
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I thought of that, I get a lot of errors, mostly because of pointers without cast, and I barely know what is a pointer. Since a string is an array of chars, shouldn't the `if` statement be somewhat like `if (strcmp(arr[j], pilot) < 0 )`? @Claies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you just need to create a swap function for string, not need for `int`

```
void swap(char ** a, char ** b) { 
    char * t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
```

Because, you sort an array of string, so using input `** arr` instead of `arr[]`
Here, the partition function:

```
int partition (char ** arr, int low, int high) { 
    char * pivot = arr[high];    // pivot 
    int i = (low - 1);  // Index of smaller element 

    for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++) { 
        // If current element is smaller than the pivot 
        if (strcmp(arr[j],pivot) < 0) { 
            i++;    // increment index of smaller element 
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]); 
        } 
    } 
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]); 
    return (i + 1); 
}
```

And, quickSort function:

```
void quickSort(char **arr, int low, int high) { 
    if (low < high) { 
        /* pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now 
           at right place */
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high); 

 
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1); 
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high); 
    } 
}
```

Then the main function for test:

```
int main(){

   char *a = "abc";
   char *b = "cdf";
   swap(&a, &b);
   printf("a = %s, b= %s\n", a, b);
   char * data[10]={"something2", "something0", "something1", "something6", "something8", "something4", "something5","something7", "something3", "something9"};
   quickSort(data, 0, 9);
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%s, ", data[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

## UPDATE:

If you want exactly an array `producer[100][63]`. You can change the declaration of the function.
In this example, i use an array `data[10][63]` for testing. In fact, you can use 100 instead of 10.

Swap function:

```
void swap(char a[63], char b[63]) { 
    char t[63];
    strcpy(t, a);
    strcpy(a, b);
    strcpy(b, t);
}
```

Then, partition function:

```
int partition (char arr[10][63], int low, int high) { 
    char * pivot = arr[high];    // pivot 
    int i = (low - 1);  // Index of smaller element 

    for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++) { 
        // If current element is smaller than the pivot 
        if (strcmp(arr[j],pivot) < 0) { 
            i++;   
            swap(arr[i], arr[j]); 
        } 
    } 
    swap(arr[i + 1], arr[high]); 
    return (i + 1); 
}
```

Finally, the quickSort function:

```
void quickSort(char arr[10][63], int low, int high) { 
    if (low < high) { 
        /* pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now 
           at right place */
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high); 

        // Separately sort elements before 
        // partition and after partition 
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1); 
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high); 
    } 
}
```

The main for test:

```
int main(){
  char data[10][63]={"something2", "something0", "something1", "something6", "something8", "something4", "something5","something7", "something3", "something9"};
   quickSort(data, 0, 9);
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%s, ", data[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Worked pretty well. Still did not work on my project. The array of strings I am using needs to be modifiable, or I think that is the error here. I am getting the error `Core Dump (Segmentation fault)`. Any idea why the array I am introducing is bugging the code? @Hitokiri

Comment: The array I need to sort is `char product_names[100][63]`

Comment: "The array of strings I am using needs to be modifiable". If you use double pointer, you can also modify the context that pointer points to. But you have to allocate for pointer first.